# ImageButton inside cell table doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, html-table, imagebutton, page-lifecycle

If I create `ImageButton` dynamically and add this into table cell

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
ImageButton imagebutton= new ImageButton();
imagebutton.imageurl=imageurl;
imagebutton.click+= new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(click);
tc.Controls.Add(imagebutton);
tr.Controls.Add(tc);
Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
```

The click event doesnt' work.

However, if I use `Panel` instead of table the `imagebutton` works. Morevoer If I add imagebutton to the `page` directly it also works.
But I need store `imagebutton` in a `table cell`.

What is a problem? 
How to make working `imagebutton` inside `asp table`?

The method click is:

```
protected void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('OK!');</script>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a problem?

This seems to be a classic **asp.net page life-cycle** problem. It's cause is probably that, a the time the click should be handled, your button, as well as your table, do not exist because you create it later in the page life cycle (say in pre_render), or you only create when not on postback, or in another control event handler.

> How to make working imagebutton inside asp table?

Your table and button creation , as well as click handler binding should be located in

page_load (even better, in Init, when using view_state for dynamic controls)

The code should run whether on  postback or not.

Hope this will help

Comment: You are right. I solved the problem. When PageLoad occurs again the system forgets to assign click event to the imagebutton.Thanks!